# Windows Docker image stops immediately

Tags: docker

docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809 -it

C:\program file\docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon container xxxx encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: {CommandLine":"-it","WorkingDirectory":"C:\","CreateStdInPipe:true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true    "CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}.

docker ps

Shows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `-it` needs to come before `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809` or else docker tries to run `-it` as a programm inside the container.

Comment: haha thanks. If I don't use the -it then shutdowns down straight away as well

Comment: You still need to use `-it` to open an interactive session, but you need to write it like this  `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809`.

Comment: Sorry I mean it works with -it in the form you said. But without -it the container does not run in the background. i.e if I use -d then it just stops and I dont see it in docker ps

Comment: By default the container starts `cmd`. To keep the container running you need to start a different program that doesn't exit or request user input.

Comment: THANKS! just stuck NOTEPAD on the end and it stays alive.